# How to authenticate to Bluemix with git?

Tags: git, authentication, ibm-cloud, devops

So my BlueMix control panel contains the comment,

```
URL de Git: https://hub.jazz.net/git/dllamber/redjuego
```

However, accessing it seems to require some sort of authentication...

```
$ git clone  https://hub.jazz.net/git/dllamber/redjuego
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/dllamber/src/redjuego/.git/
error: The requested URL returned error: 401 Unauthorized while accessing https://hub.jazz.net/git/dllamber/redjuego/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

How do I pass my username and password to git for this purpose?  And what do I use... my IBM ID (a no-longer-deliverable email address) and password? Or the deliverable e-mail address associated with that ID as the user ID? Or something else?

Comment: For questions regarding Bluemix login, pleas post at IBM developerWorks Answers (https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html) and/or open a Bluemix support ticket from the Account and Support widget at the upper right corner of the Bluemix dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access a private repo or one that requires authentication, use this format:

```
https://your_alias:your_IBM_ID_password@hub.jazz.net/alias/project_name
```

Documentation on this [can be found here](https://hub.jazz.net/docs/git/#repositories).

Hope this helps!

Comment: To clarify, _your-alias_ is the Jazz username.